# pandas Series.to_dict() type conversion from numpy types seems inconsistent

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm not sure if this is design intent and my expectations are wrong but it seems to me that the type conversion of numpy types to python types from Series.to_dict() is inconsistent. By comparison, a similar experiment with DataFrame.to_dict() results does what I expect.

venv running: Python 3.7.5, pandas==0.25.3

Here is the example code to illustrate:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {'A': 1, 'B': None}
    df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    print("original DataFrame:")
    print(df)

    print("Series.to_dict():")
    res = df.loc[0,:].to_dict()
    for i in res.items():
        print(type(i[1]))

    print("DataFrame.to_dict('records'):")
    res = df.to_dict('records')[0]
    for i in res.items():
        print(type(i[1]))
```

This code produces the following output:
original DataFrame:

```
   A     B
0  1  None
Series.to_dict():
<class 'numpy.int64'>
<class 'NoneType'>
DataFrame.to_dict('records'):
<class 'int'>
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Notice that the value for column A is coming out as a numpy.int64 in the case of Series.to_dict() whereas exporting the DataFrame.to_dict('records') and taking the first row from the list of records has the column A value coming out as a python int.

Interestingly, if I remove the None value from column B and replace it with another integer value, I get different behavior in the type conversion. As follows:

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
    df = pd.DataFrame([data])
    print("original DataFrame:")
    print(df)

    print("Series.to_dict():")
    res = df.loc[0,:].to_dict()
    for i in res.items():
        print(type(i[1]))

    print("DataFrame.to_dict('records'):")
    res = df.to_dict('records')[0]
    for i in res.items():
        print(type(i[1]))
```

The above code yields the following output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
Series.to_dict():
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
DataFrame.to_dict('records'):
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

In this case, both the Series.to_dict() and the DataFrame.to_dict() behave the same way.

Please clarify this for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics, but dictionary keys and values mean different things for a series vs a DF

Comment: whats wrong with that result? you used the 'records' type of dict conversion which return a list of dicts... and you took the first element

Comment: @MadPhysicist: You should see in my code example that I'm only ever printing the type of the values in the dictionary - never the keys. The point of my observation/question is that the data types of the dictionary values differ depending on whether I call to_dict() from a DataFrame object or from a Series even though the underlying data is the same in both cases.

Comment: @adirabargil, please see my response to Mad Physicist above. Perhaps I didn't explain my question clearly enough. The bottom line is data types of the value fields are not always getting converted back to native Python types and it's not clear to me why that is.

Comment: Ok now i see...